# Spring AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter and annotation-reading interceptors

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have a basic Spring MVC controller that looks like this:

```
@Controller
public void MyController {
     @RequestMapping("/secret")
     public String show() {
         return "secret.jsp";
     }
}
```

I am going to have several similar URLs that can only be reached by signed-in users.  Since this is a cross-cutting concern, I'd like to use AOP, and I'd like to make this work via annotations.  In other words, I'd like to throw a `@RequiresLogin` annotation on every controller method that needs to be secret.

AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter supports the concept of interceptors, which seems on the surface like the right way to go for this.  However, I want to know which method is going to be invoked so that I can check it for my `@RequiresLogin` annotation.  I see that there's an "Object handler" parameter that's passed in, but I'm not sure how to turn that into a Class and Method that will be invoked.

Ideas?

Comment: Wouldn't Spring Security be able to handle this without the need of you annotating your controllers?

Comment: Probably, but our project isn't using Spring Security, and I'd like to modify filter behavior on methods in genearl, not just for authorization.  Perhaps add a custom extra header for certain methods, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As axtavt writes correctly, Spring-AOP works well with controllers if using proxy-target-class. But there is also the possibility of using JDK proxies if you follow some (tedious) conventions:

> **Working with interface-based @Controller classes**
>
> A common pitfall when working with
>   annotated controller classes happens
>   when applying functionality that
>   requires creating a proxy proxy for
>   the controller object (e.g.
>   `@Transactional` methods). Usually you
>   will introduce an interface for the
>   controller in order to use JDK dynamic
>   proxies. **To make this work you must
>   move the `@RequestMapping` annotations
>   to the interface** as the mapping
>   mechanism can only "see" the interface
>   exposed by the proxy. As an
>   alternative, you may choose to
>   activate proxy-target-class="true" in
>   the configuration for the
>   functionality applied to the
>   controller (in our transaction
>   scenario in `<tx:annotation-driven />`).
>   Doing so indicates that CGLIB-based
>   subclass proxies should be used
>   instead of interface-based JDK
>   proxies. For more information on
>   various proxying mechanisms see
>   Section 7.6, [“Proxying mechanisms”](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-proxying).

**Source:** [**15.3.2 Mapping requests with @RequestMapping**](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping)

Answer (score 2):

There are no good ways to get a method signature in the interceptor.

Try to apply a regular AOP advise to your controller, Spring MVC plays well with it as long as target class proxying is used.

Answer (score 1):

While using spring security would be the optimal approach here, you can implement similar functionality using Spring Aspects.  Here is an example of using an Aspect to check for a method containing a particular Annotation.

```
@Aspect
public class MyAspect {
    @Around("execution(* com.test.controllers..*.**(..)) && " +
            "within(@org.springframework.sterotype.Controller *)")
    public Object execute(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) {
        Object target = joinPoint.getTarget();
        if (target != null) {
            Signature tSig = joinPoint.getSignature();
            if (tSig instanceof MethodSignature) {
                MethodSignature mSig = (MethodSignature) tSig;
                Method method = mSig.getMethod();
                if (method != null && method.isAnnotationPresent(MyAnnotation.class)) {
                    // do something
                    // parameters are available from joinPoint.getArgs();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // allow method invocation to continue
    return joinPoint.proceed();
}
```

The format of the @Around advice will be specific to your application.  In this example, it checks for any class annotated with Controller in the package com.test.controllers and all subpackages.  See http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/aop.html for additional options.

Good luck!

Comment: Yes, but the restrictions outlined in axtavt's and my own post apply (unless you use AspectJ compile-time-weaving)

Answer (score 1):

How about ResolveHandlerMethodInterceptor using reflection.
Below code is experimental and version-dependent(spring 3.0.2).

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationContextUtils;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerInterceptor;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter;

public class ResolveHandlerMethodInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {
    public final static String HANDLER_METHOD = "handlerMethod";
    // Here is your servlet name
    public final static String SERVLET_NAME = "XXXXX";


    @Override
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object object, ModelAndView modelAndView)
            throws Exception {
        Method handlerMethod = (Method) request.getAttribute(HANDLER_METHOD);
        System.out.println("postHandle>>>" + handlerMethod);
    }

    @Override
    public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object object, Exception exception)
            throws Exception {
        Method handlerMethod = (Method) request.getAttribute(HANDLER_METHOD);
        System.out.println("afterCompletion>>>" + handlerMethod);
    }

    @Override   
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object object) throws Exception {

        ServletContext servletContext = request.getSession().getServletContext();
        String attrName = FrameworkServlet.SERVLET_CONTEXT_PREFIX + SERVLET_NAME;
        WebApplicationContext context = WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(servletContext, attrName);
        AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter adapter = context.getBean(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.class);     

        Method getMethodResolverMethod = adapter.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("getMethodResolver", Object.class);
        getMethodResolverMethod.setAccessible(true);
        Object servletHandlerMethodResolver = getMethodResolverMethod.invoke(adapter, object);

        Method resolveHandlerMethod = servletHandlerMethodResolver.getClass().getMethod("resolveHandlerMethod", HttpServletRequest.class);
        resolveHandlerMethod.setAccessible(true);
        Method handlerMethod = (Method) resolveHandlerMethod.invoke(servletHandlerMethodResolver, request);
        request.setAttribute(HANDLER_METHOD, handlerMethod);

        System.out.println("preHandle>>>" + handlerMethod);

        return true;
    }
}
```

==reference==
http://toby.epril.com/?p=934
http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/org/springframework/spring-webmvc/3.0.2.RELEASE/spring-webmvc-3.0.2.RELEASE-sources.jar!/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/annotation/AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java?format=ok

Answer (score 0):

So, these approaches listed are good, but they all have limitations.  The AOP stuff is a good idea, but its limitation is that I need a way to get ahold of the request and response objects if I want to redirect or modify the response.  The controller methods don't necessarily need the requests and responses, and requiring that they appear seems inelegant. I could use spring magic to get the request object from the Aspect, but I couldn't find a way to get the response.

Eventually, I came up with a middle way.  I used a filter bean to get the request and the response objects and store them in a ThreadLocal.  Then I created an aspect that has a reference to that filter, so that it could easily see the request and response objects.

Then I made the aspect wrap around methods based on the annotation, so I didn't even need to check on whether the annotation was present using code.

This combination approach appears to be working perfectly!

The only downside is that I can't figure out a good way to write an integration test that verifies that the aspect is invoked when there's an incoming request to that URL.  It's a little scary that removing a single annotation leaves all my tests passing but allows unauthorized users through.

Thanks everybody for the great suggestions!

Comment: Sorry, I no longer have access to that code. I don't think it'd take more than a day or so to reproduce it, though.